Is the aws + jenkins pipeline combination correct to do this?

I'm practicing  EC2 + Jenkins in Aws
but while i'm working on jenkins inside an ec2 instance
i have a question
my plan is ( jenkins instacne , docker+node+express instance , docker+node+express instance ) combination.

After realizing , that express can't be installed in Jenkins
so i realized that i had to work in jenkins pipeline
In one word.
install Jenkins in ec2 instance and and set up Express pipeline within it
Please correct me, if i'm mistaken

Could you explain what you mean by 'set up Express pipeline'? Are you trying to create a Jenkins pipeline to build and deploy an Express application?

i wanted to manage Jenkins efficiently so i think method Rather than managing everything with jenkins pipeline instance i though it would be a good idea to modularize the instance into multiple instances , fill only the building parts with Jenkins , and manage the remaining Front and Backend parts separately on the instance server

This is my first time using Jenkins, so the explanation may be a bit strange.

The best thing to do is

Run your Jenkins as container in one of the instances.
Use EC2 plugin to spin nodes while running jobs which uses an underlying ami.
Install all your dependencies and tools in that ami and run jobs on it.
Its best practice to not install tolls and dependencies in Jenkins.

Thanks,
Nitin

i'm sorry i didn't quite get that  Use EC2 plugin to spin nodes while running jobs which uses an underlying ami.  if i understand correctly creating ec2 instance -> set up ami -> install node.js Did i say that correctly?
